Excel VBA Macro Draw System Select Random cells
I’ve done a winner draw macro before where you click a button and a winner is selected from another sheet of data. Now i want to select 10 random winners by one click of a button. How can i do that please?
This is my code but it selects only one winner per click. How to modify to make it 10 winners with one click only

Sub Button2_Click()
 
Dim sh As Worksheet, randnum As Long, nextrecord As Range
 
Set sh = Sheet2
Randomize
randnum = Int(2273 * Rnd) + 2
 
 
Set nextrecord = Sheet1.Range("C16").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
nextrecord = sh.Range("A" & randnum)
 
 
End Sub


This code uses Scripting.Dictionary to store randomized numbers.
Sub Button2_Click()
 
Dim sh As Worksheet, nextrecord As Range, randn As Long
Dim randnum As Dictionary, arr
Set randnum = New Dictionary
Set sh = Sheet2
Randomize
For i = 1 To 10
    randn = Int(2273 * Rnd()) + 2
    If randnum.Exists(randn) Then   'check for ident value
        i = i - 1  
    Else
        randnum.Add randn, randn
    End If
Next i
arr = randnum.Items   'contains dictionary items
For i = 0 To 9   'loop through arr
    Set nextrecord = Sheet1.Range("C16").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    nextrecord = sh.Range("A" & arr(i))
Next i
 
End Sub


Thank you. But how do i make it select a random cell from my other sheet? Random 10 cells and inserts them into my current sheet

In my code sh=Sheet2 is the sheet where the winners are listed in column A. Sheet1 is the (must) actual sheet displayed. You used codenames, which are not the displayed names on the tabs of the sheets. To use the sheetnames need e.g.  Worksheets("Sheet1") to apply.  Set nextrecord = Sheet1.Range("C16").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) moves up from C16, so there must be at least 11 empty cells to run properly. If this not solve the issue post a screenshot of the result sheet and the source sheet to exactly see the data on them.

Ok now i get it! It was throwing an error because I didn’t add the reference. Thank you so much!
